# Expand dataframe based on new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
     month=c("July", "August", "August"),
     day=c(31, 1, 2),
     time=c(12, 12, 12))

   month day time
1   July  31   12
2 August   1   12
3 August   2   12
```

I have a text file of times (in decimal format) and I want to replace the "time" column with all of the times from the text file. There are multiple days in the text file, with over 300 records for each.

```
7-31-2016 #the days are all concatenated together, this line represents the beginning of one day (July 31)
13.12344
13.66445
13.76892
...
8-1-2016 #here is another day (August 1)
14.50333
14.52000
14.53639
...
```

However, the text file is much longer than the current dataframe-- it has 393 records. So I would like the resulting dataframe to look something like this:

```
    month   day       time
5    July    31   13.12344
6    July    31   13.66445
7    July    31   13.76892
.....
393 August    1   14.50333
394 August    1   14.52000
394 August    1   14.53639
```

Basically I just need to be able to expand my current dataframe to match the number of records from the new file, while keeping the same day. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: How is your text file struture ?

Comment: Please provide the dataframe or list read from the text file.

Comment: @NicoCoallier The text file structure is exactly as I've listed in the post. It is basically just a list of times that are concatenated together. The date indicates a new day (e.g. July 31, Aug 1, etc.).

Comment: @OmaymaS I'm not sure what you want? Both the text file and the existing dataframe are very large, so I just provided a sample.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what's hanging you up as well. This seems like you want to just format both data frames to have a month and day column and merge them on those. Are you having trouble formatting the second data frame?

Comment: The first step would be to clean up that text file   `txt <- data.frame(value = c('7-31-2016', '13.12344', '13.66445', '13.76892', '8-1-2016', '14.50333', '14.52000', '14.53639'))` and then something like this....
    
   `txt$dash <- grepl('-', txt$value)`  but i don't know how to expand the data frame based on that logical value so that you have a `date` and `time` column...then you just joing to your data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create txt data
txt <- data.frame(x = c('7-31-2016', '13.12344', '13.66445', '13.76892', '8-1-2016', '14.50333', '14.52000', '14.53639'))
# Load Your data 
df <- data.frame(
  month=c("July", "August", "August"),
  day=c(31, 1, 2),
  time=c(12, 12, 12))

# Need a year to join dates
df$year <- 2016

# Create date column
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$month, "/", df$day, "/", df$year), format = "%B/%d/%Y")

# Find values with dashes, then replaces with /
txt$dash <- grepl('-', txt$x)
txt$x <- gsub("-", "/", txt$x)

# Adds new columns
library(dplyr)
txt <- mutate(txt, date = ifelse(dash==TRUE, as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), NA))
txt <- mutate(txt, time = ifelse(dash==FALSE, as.numeric(x), NA))

# Fill down values
library(zoo)
txt$date <- na.locf(txt$date)

# Removes NA and keeps necessary columns
txt <- txt[!is.na(txt$time),]
txt <- txt[c("date", "time")]

# Merge
output <- merge(df, txt, by = "date")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to merge your existing data.frame `df`, which has only 3 rows, with `new_text`, which has many. Use:

```
merge(df, new_text, all.y = T) #all.y will interpolate new rows for the ones that don't match
```

For more information see `?merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the txt file into mergeable `dataframe`:

```
 df$V2=as.numeric(df$V1)
 Temp=is.na(df$V2)
 df$V2=NA
 df$V2[Temp]=df$V1[Temp]
 df$V2=na.locf(df$V2)
 df=df[!Temp,]

        V1        V2
2 13.12344 7/31/2016
3 13.66445 7/31/2016
4 13.76892 7/31/2016
6 14.50333  8/1/2016
7    14.52  8/1/2016
8 14.53639  8/1/2016
```